# Powershell Apex Data Loader v29 CLI error

Tags: data-loader

I'm trying to run apex data loader CLI from windows powershell. I actually managed to start the CLI from powershell however I'm getting the following errors:

> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,380 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:389) - Using built-in logging configuration, no log-conf.xml in C:\temp\log-conf.xml
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,395 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:391) - The log has been initialized
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,400 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:327) - config dir created at c:\Temp\SalesForce\SF
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,419 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:355) - The controller config has been initialized
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,421 INFO  [main] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:116) - Initializing process engine
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,421 INFO  [main] process.ProcessRunner run (ProcessRunner.java:119) - Loading parameters
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,421 INFO  [main] config.LastRun load (LastRun.java:96) - Last run info will be saved in file: c:\Temp\SalesForce\SF\null_lastRun.properties
>
> 2014-02-05 22:48:59,437 FATAL [main] process.ProcessRunner topLevelError (ProcessRunner.java:238) - Unable to run process null
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.salesforce.dataloader.action.OperationInfo.
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:162)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:100)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:253)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.salesforce.dataloader.action.OperationInfo.
>           at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.getEnum(Config.java:459)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.getOperationInfo(Config.java:999)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:123)
>           ... 2 more

As far as I can see my process-conf.xml is correct:

```
<entry key="process.operation" value="insert"/>
```

Could you please advise what could be the problem?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
1. It works when executing process.bat manually from standard command line.
2. In powershell I'm doing the following:
& $cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5

the variables have the following values:

> PS C:\temp> echo $cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
>   c:\Programs\Apex_Data_Loader\Java\bin\java.exe
>   -cp c:\Programs\Apex_Data_Loader\dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar
>   -Dsalesforce.config.dir=c:\temp\salesforce\sf\ com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner CA1